# How to start session in my web application after successful facebook login?

Tags: facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am using Facebook login with the Facebook javascript sdk. I have implemented all the login flow. I want to know what I should to do to start a session on my application. From Facebook docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web:

Once your app knows the login status of the person using it, it can do one of the following:

1. If the person is logged into Facebook and your app, redirect them to
   your app's logged in experience.
2. If the person is logged into Facebook but not your app, prompt them with the Login dialog.
3. If the person is not logged into Facebook, prompt them with the Login dialog.

I want to work on the first one: redirect them to my app's logged in experience. But I do not know how to recognize the user and start the new session on the server so that he can access personal data. I thought a possible solution might be to send the accessToken received on the client to my server, then ask to Facebook's servers if that is a valid token, if so then start a new session for the recognized user, otherwise ignore the request. Is that a correct flow?